# Assistance in Pivoting Table Dynamic Rows to Dynamic Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of data that needs the columns to be the `EventId` (the number of these can change, and so need to be dynamic) with the rows being Employee and the summary data of each `EventId/Employee` being the `Sum(CallFee)`.

I was thinking a Pivot would work well for this however unsure how to do this with the dynamic number of Events. Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

The following is the source SQL

```
SELECT Group, Employee, EventId, CallFee
FROM A
GROUP BY Group, Employee
ORDER BY Employee
```

This is the desired output:

[image: This is the desired output]

This is the source table:

[image: The source table]

Comment: Please don't use images, format a small sample of data in text. [Why not?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

***Please use sample data preferably in text format instead of images for any code.***

A PIVOT can help you to group rows and convert it into columns. But the result you are expecting I wonder whether you can get this thru PIVOT.

And if you are not sure about how PIVOT works, you can google for it before posting question to wide community forum. You can have a look at the PIVOT in SQL Server [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15).

Anyway, I think below sample should work for you.

```
SELECT
[Group],
[Employee],
ISNULL([21837], 0) AS [21837],
ISNULL([21838], 0) AS [21838],
ISNULL([21839], 0) AS [21839],
ISNULL([21840], 0) AS [21840],
ISNULL([21841], 0) AS [21841],
ISNULL([21837], 0) + ISNULL([21838], 0) + ISNULL([21839], 0) + ISNULL([21840], 0) + ISNULL([21841], 0) AS Total
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM TableA
) AS T
PIVOT
(
    SUM(CallFee)
    FOR EventId IN ([21837], [21838], [21839], [21840], [21841])
) AS P
ORDER BY [Group];
```

If the number of columns are not known, have a look at this [thread](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-pivot/). You can easily specify dynamic columns using stuff and many other ways.